# Why can't CPL be changed when running in an unprivileged ring (user mode)?

Tags: x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture, protected-mode

If the current privilege level is encoded in `CS`, which is modifiable by user-mode code, why can’t user-mode code modify `CS` to change `CPL`?

Comment: It can: just execute `syscall` or `int3` ;)

Comment: @Ruslan SYSCALL invokes an OS system-call handler at privilege level 0, but in that case, the OS is the one who put the address in CS (CS point to the address of the handler ), not the user

Comment: Not, it's not the OS directly: it's the `syscall` instruction which changes `cs`, along with a bunch of other registers. Same for interrupt handlers (though they don't use MSRs to find targets, instead using interrupt gates in the IDT).

Comment: But who configure those address in the first place it's the OS roll to set up the IDT for example at boot time

Comment: If your userspace program has direct access to the GDT, IDT or LDT, it's a security problem in your OS. Of course the OS has to create all the descriptors. And it's not going to let userspace to switch CPL arbitrarily.

Comment: What is your actual question? Is it "What mechanism prevents change of CPL on loading of a selector into CS?"? Or maybe "What is the rationale for this impossibility?"?

Comment: What mechanism prevents change of CPL on loading of a selector into CS in user-mode?

Comment: What environment are you testing on? QEMU? Bochs? Real hardware (There is a reason I ask that question first). Second question. How are you changing _CS_? (What instructions). `MOV` and `POP` can't alter _CS_ or they throw an exception. That leaves FAR `CALL` and `JMP`'s indirectly through Call Gates (or indirectly via syscall/traps/interrupts etc) or using `IRED` or `RETF` (Far return). The instruction set reference for the instruction you use to modify _CS_ will include the rules what CPL changes are allowed (privilege level changes involve checks with RPL and the the DPL of the _CS_)

Comment: This question is based on a [faulty assumption](https://www.reddit.com/r/asm/comments/6c3rnv/why_exactly_mov_csxx_is_an_restricted_instruction/).

Comment: @MichaelPetch let's say everything that can change it ( FAR CALL/JMP IRET/IRETD/IRETQ )

Comment: I should've also asked a question about the title of this Q. _modifying CS from UserMode doesn't affect CPL_. Was there some specific piece of code that you used to modify CS that resulted in no change? Usually with changing CS indirectly (via other instructions previously listed) one of two things will happen. You'll get an exception because you don't have proper permission to change the CPL to another or you are transitioned into another ring and a CPL change will take place (there are some exceptions if you use conforming code segments where CPL doesn't change and code runs with CPL<>DPL).

Comment: @MichaelPetch there is no piece of code actually, just a guy asked me and I couldn't answer him

Comment: The real answer as to what happens with each instruction that may alter CPL (JMP/CALL/IRET/RETF etc) is in the Instruction Set Architecture reference for each instruction. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/

Comment: I will check it

Comment: I have a hunch that whoever asked you the question is/was confused although I can't say since I can't ask them these questions directly.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Normally I don't give this type of questions a big deal but when a student stops you at class and I promise him a good answer, so I better do it  (^_^)

Comment: @MichaelPetch question is taken verbatim from from the book practical reverse engineering, so there ya go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is broad, but I can give some general information and links referencing the [Instruction Set architecture](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/) (ISA) which describes all the instructions.

You can't [`MOV`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov) or [`POP`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pop) a value into *CS* (on 286+<sup>1</sup>) so you are prevented from modifying *CS* that way. For example for `POP` there is a rule:

> The POP instruction cannot pop a value into the CS register. To load the CS register from the stack, use the RET instruction.

And the rule for `MOV` is similar:

> The MOV instruction cannot be used to load the CS register.

You can modify *CS* indirectly through [`syscall`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/syscall), [`sysenter`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sysenter), [FAR `jmp`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp) (via call gate), [FAR `call`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call) (via call gate), [`iret`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/iret:iretd), [`retf`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret)(FAR return) or [`int`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/intn:into:int3:int1) . You can review the [ISA](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/) for each instruction and what privilege level checks are applied. You can't arbitrarily change CPL if you don't have the privilege and access rights to do so.

Under most circumstances if you have the privilege to affect a change to CPL it will be changed. If you don't have the required privileges you get an exception (privilege level checks usually involve [RPL, CPL, DPL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36631763/3857942)). If using [conforming code segments](http://www.logix.cz/michal/doc/i386/chp06-03.htm) (a different topic) you can request to execute code using a code segment with a higher privileged DPL but the CPL will remain unchanged. It is a case where the CPL and DPL (Descriptor privilege level) of *CS* can be different while code is executing.

---

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup>You were allowed to modify *CS* via `POP` and `MOV` on 8088/8086 processors.